# Qt4 - How to add a row in a QTableWidget when sorting is enable?

Tags: qt4, qtablewidget

I have a `QTableWidget` with which I can add rows by pushing a button. The problem is that I have `_table->setSortingEnabled(true);`, and when I'll insert a new row, I won't know where it is. Because since I have set the table sortable, when I add a row, this row will move to it's position (depending on which column is sorted). How can I know which one it is then?

Example with one column (Name) sorted by alphabetical order:

```
Name |
------
abc
toto
zozo
```

If I now add a row like follow :

```
int newRow = _table->rowCount();

_table->insertRow(newRow);

QTableWidgetItem *item1 = new QTableWidgetItem;
item1->setText("boom");
_table->setItem(newRow, 0, item1);
```

The row will go between 'abc' and 'toto'.

```
Name |
------
abc
     <<< boom
toto
zozo
```

Here it'll work properly, but I have multiple columns and if now I try for example:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item2 = new QTableWidgetItem;
item1->setText("45");
_table->setItem(newRow, 1, item2);
```

The value that'll change is the value of the second column of 'zozo' and not the one I want, 'boom'.

I tried to explain with an example the problem, I hope it helped. So how can I add a new row, set it's text for each of its column if I have the sorting enable on my `QTableWidget` ?

**Edit : Answer from nonexplosive (in the comments) :**

Just need to do like follow for the second `QWidgetItem` :

```
QTableWidgetItem *item2 = new QTableWidgetItem;
item1->setText("45");
_table->setItem(item1->row(), 1, item2); // change newRow by item1->row()
```

Comment: Look into `QTableWidgetItem::row()` to get the row of `item1`

Comment: it may be easier to use model/view for this, but why not inserting the row just at the end and sort it by the last column where it was sorted?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to disable sorting, via setSortingEnabled(false), before inserting and re-enable it after you finish.

Answer (score 1):

Create hidden column that will contain id of every row, so when you add row just use `void QTableWidget scrollToItem (const QTableWidgetItem  *item , QAbstractItemView::ScrollHint hint=EnsureVisible )` to scroll table to that row.

> Scrolls the view if necessary to ensure that the item is visible. The
>   hint parameter specifies more precisely where the item should be
>   located after the operation.

Once you have row id, you can also change color of the new row (cell by cell) with `void QTableWidgetItem::setBackground ( const QBrush & brush )` until next new row is added.

Doing both of those suggestions will ensure that newly added row is visible to you.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to insert a new row using `rowCount`

```
int row = table->rowCount();
table->insertRow(row);
```

Then for the **first** `QTableWidgetItem` you need to call `QTableWidget::setItem(row, item)` with the **`rowCount`**

```
table->setItem(row, item);
```

For **subsequent** `QTableWidgetItems`, you use `QTableWidgetItem::row()` from the first `QTableWidgetItem`, which may have moved due to sorting

```
table->setItem(first_item->row, item);
```

Here is an example of calling `QTableWidget::setItem(row, item)` from within a loop, where you use `row` when `index == 0` and `item[0]` when `index != 0`:

```
void App::onAddRow()
{
    std::vector<QTableWidgetItem*> items;

    items.push_back(new QTableWidgetItem("foo"));
    items.push_back(new QTableWidgetItem("bar"));
    items.push_back(new QTableWidgetItem("baz"));
    items.push_back(new QTableWidgetItem("bang"));

    int row = table->rowCount();
    table->insertRow(row);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i)
    {
        table->setItem(i == 0 ? row : items[0]->row(), i, items[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only work if you are sorting the table by the 1st column. What you can do instead is first insert the item of the sorted column and store this item's row. Then you can use this row to insert all the other items. I found it simpler to just disable and re-enable the sorting.